# How can I pass non-consecutive parameters to a function?

Tags: php, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

```
function foo($x="", $y="", $z=""){
    echo $x .'-'. $y .'-'. $z;
}
foo('hello', $z='world');
> hello-world-
```

I would like to print 'hello--world'. Do I need to specify all arguments between x and z to accomplish that?

Comment: Only rightmost function parameters may be omitted. Alternative would be to change the function to accept an array.

Comment: Yes you have to

Comment: It seems to me that would be a nice feature to support :(

Comment: Use an array of arguments?

Comment: "Named arguments" has been discussed in the PHP Internals group on a couple of occasions, but hasn't ever been accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also suggest you another alias:

```
function foo($x="", $y="", $z=""){
    return $x .'-'. $y .'-'. $z;
}

function fooXZ($x="", $z=""){
    return foo($x, "", $z);
}

echo fooXZ('hello', 'world');

> hello-world-
```

and this because if you dont need a parameter, .. .maybe this means you need another function.

Comment: This would be much, much nicer if the methods could share the same name like in Java

Comment: I love php. I hate the impossibility to do that in php =(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to specify all parameters (arguments) in your function (except the last one!) if it is written like in your example.

One alternative would be to instead pass an array as parameter, but that would not work if the method/function is called from a URL.

You can not specify which parameter to pass when you make the call like in your example:

```
foo('hello', $z='world');
```

You are only passing the second parameter in your example.

You would have to make either of the following calls to the function:

```
foo('hello', 'world');
foo('hello', '', 'world');
```